# Alternative to Keycloak Gatekeeper/ Luketo Proxy

Tags: oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy, keycloak-gatekeeper

Keycloak Gatekeeper/ Luketo Proxy has recently become deprecated and I need an alternative. I need to have an alternative oAuth revers proxy solution that only authenticates on a particular path and when it does, it passes through users details as headers.

The URLs I need to authenticate against are

- https://example.com/api/route.secure
- https://example.com/api/route.secure2

All other URL paths are open.

I have been looking at oAuth2 Proxy which is similar, but doesn't have the --resource option, which I was making use of to only authenticate one URL. It does have the --skip-auth-regex option but because of it using re2 it doesn't support negative look ups.

Comment: I see that is a fork in GitHub that looks like its been actively maintained [here](https://github.com/gogatekeeper/gatekeeper). So I'll just use that for now, still open to suggestions though :)

Comment: Indeed, but here's a question. How long it will be maintained? Should everyone take a look around for something else?.....